# Why does QFile::canReadLine() always return false?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qfile

I was trying to read a file line by line using

```
while (file.canReadLine()) {
    QString line = QString::fromUtf8(file.readLine());
    qDebug() << line;
}
```

but `QFile::canReadLine()` always returns false, even though `file.readLine()` succeeds and reads the next line each time it's called (I've tested that).

Is it supposed always return false? The docs say that it **always returns false for unbuffered devices**, but isn't QFile buffered?

I'm using Qt 4.7.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that this is **not the expected behavior**. It is a bug, and it [has already been reported](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-24367).

It affects Qt versions 4.7.4, 4.8.0, 4.8.1, 4.8.2.